# how to know which method is been called from JavaScript which gets result in JsAlert

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am calling the method like this

```
mWebview.loadUrl("javascript:alert(myMethod())");
```

I get the result in the method below

```
@Override
public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
  //the return value from javascript()
  String returnJsValue=message;
}
```

but I don't know this is result of which method how to distinguish it
for eg I have multiple methods in my javascript

```
function getName() {
  return name;
}

function getAge() {
  return name;
}

function getGender() {
  return name;
}
```

like this three methods call will be diffrent but I will get the return value in Jsalert if I am calling the method in alert method of js

Comment: 1 - Why ? 2 - You can always add the name in the return of the methods or concat in the alert `(alert('methods 1|' + getMethods1()).

Comment: It will note be feasible if we do so again we need to spilt and remove the value of the method from the return string;

Comment: Why do you want to remove it if you want to now where is it from ? I still don't understand the why so hard to find a solution. This seems a bit strange. And what contains the `url` variable ? could you not use it if you find `javascript:alert(myMethod())`.

Comment: url variable does not have the method name

Comment: `Why do you want to remove it if you want to now where is it from ? I still don't understand the why so hard to find a solution.`

Comment: i have 3 methods suppose getName,getGender,getMail. 3 of this method will return a string value in onJsAlert how can i recongnise which string is name which is gender which is mail

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125175/discussion-between-axelh-and-awez-shaikh).